Intercept the power button press event using on an macOS app using swift and swiftUI
I am writing a small macOS app in which the app intercept all the keyboard events and nullify them.I use CGEventType to achieve this goal, but CGEventType does not include the power button on macbook. When I press the power button, the app is unable to intercept. So I wonder if there is a way to include the power button too. Big thanks in acvance.
this is code I have:
private func startKeyboardMonitoring() {
    let eventMask = (1 << CGEventType.keyDown.rawValue) | (1 << CGEventType.keyUp.rawValue) | (1 << CGEventType.flagsChanged.rawValue)
    guard let eventTap = CGEvent.tapCreate(
        tap: .cgSessionEventTap,
        place: .headInsertEventTap,
        options: .defaultTap,
        eventsOfInterest: CGEventMask(eventMask),
        callback: { (proxy, type, event, refcon) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>? in
            let keyCallback = Unmanaged<EventMonitor>.fromOpaque(refcon!).takeUnretainedValue()
            return keyCallback.keyboardCallback(proxy: proxy, type: type, event: event)
        },
        userInfo: Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()
    ) else {
        print("Failed to create keyboard event tap")
        return
    }
    
    self.keyboardEventTap = eventTap
    
    let runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0)
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, .commonModes)
    CGEvent.tapEnable(tap: eventTap, enable: true)
}

private func keyboardCallback(proxy: CGEventTapProxy, type: CGEventType, event: CGEvent) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>? {
    let keyCode = event.getIntegerValueField(.keyboardEventKeycode)
    let flags = event.flags
    
    let isKeyComboPressed = keyCode == stopMonitoringKeyCombo.keyCode && flags.contains(stopMonitoringKeyCombo.flags)
    
    if isKeyComboPressed && !lastKeyComboState {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.isMonitoring.toggle()
        }
    }
    
    lastKeyComboState = isKeyComboPressed
    
    return (isMonitoring && !isKeyComboPressed) ? nil : Unmanaged.passRetained(event)
}


i doubt that will be possible.  why would the OS or the HW ever want that?  sounds like a malware.

Someone did it. When his app runs , the power button of my macbook is also nullified. I don't know how he managed it.

Just to prevent my kids messing around my keyboard ,when I watch videos.

probably not with swift.

maybe Objective-C? I don't know.

Everything you can do with Objective-C, you can do with Swift.

Then how on earth did he managed to do it . This is driving me crazy. I can give you guys the link of the app that can do the trick. Just in case you might think I am lying.
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/cleanmykeyboard/id6468120888?mt=12

Can you intercept the media keys? Do you also want to intercept forced shut down? Have you tried NSEventTypeSystemDefined?

wow.. im surprised!

What is stopMonitoringKeyCombo?

That is just key combonation to toggle the interception.

Thank you Willeke. You are a life saver. I figured it out the solution to block all the keyboard events. Thanks a lot guys. Really appriciate your response.

It would possibly help others if you post your solution as an answer.

It's just like what Willeke said, using NSEventTypeSystemDefined.
